# Home-built PC will beep with no problems and display the Gigabyte logo, but I can't get to BIOS setup or anything

Tags: windows, boot, bios, uefi, computer-building

Parts:
Motherboard: Gigabyte `GA-970A-DS3P FX`
Power source: `Jupiter 600 watt 80 plus bronze`
Hard Drive (HDD, not solid state): `Seagate Barracuda 1TB`
CPU/Processor: `AMD FX 6300`
Graphics Card/GPU: `GTX 750 Ti`
RAM: `Kingdom Hyper X Fury 8GB ddr 3`

Wow, that's a lot of parts for one computer...

So, my PC a friend and I worked on building has finally gotten to booting. It boots, showing the logo, but neither spamming or holding the keys it displays does anything and it goes to a blue screen then stops outputting stuff before doing it all again.
[screenshot 1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nintendo8/nintendo8.github.io/master/Screenshots/IMG_4144.PNG) [screenshot 2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nintendo8/nintendo8.github.io/master/Screenshots/IMG_4145.PNG)

What else should I try? I'm pretty sure it's not the keyboard, as the keyboard worked when my friend was using their PC for this setup step.

Thank you for your time and help!

Note: the power source fan makes a horrible noise, but I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: Note: there should maybe be a `gigabyte-motherboard` tag.

Comment: You are using USB Keyboard? Plug it into the USB2 port?

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick checklist below.

1. **Re-seat** all hardware (RAM, Graphics Card), then make sure they're all seated correctly and snug.
2. Ensure all power supply cables are securely attached.
3. Press the 'Clear CMOS' button.

   [image: Clear CMOS]

**As a last resort**, you could consider flashing the BIOS to latest firmware. However, you need to first identify which revision your motherboard is before updating firmware.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot it seems that it tries to enter to the BIOS/UEFI but fails for some reason.

Your should try to Clear CMOS to make sure the BIOS has factory default settings. You have to shortcut the CLR_CMOS jumper on the motherboard and power on the system (page 12 in the Manual if it's a revision 2.1 board).

If it not helps maybe you should try to replace the RAM module, the GPU card or even the CPU.

If none of them helps then it might be a faulty motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find an IBM PS2 style keyboard give this a try on bios entry- A lot of devices don't work on the USB3 ports until the system has loaded. You could Try another USB port too.

If you cant find the bios clear jumper, just remove the battery on the board and turn it off at the wall for 30 seconds.

Remove ALL devices from the computer - just have power supply, keyboard, screen.

If you don't know what I mean by PS/2 - here is a diagram. Look bottom left.
[image: motherboard ports]

The Hard Disk you are using -- Does it have a system already on it? It may have a bad boot sector causing the system lock. Try without the Hard Disk attached.

You are pressing the key with DELETE or DEL and not the backspace?

Comment: I’m pressing the small Delete, not the backspace key